# CSS3 + Javascript - Will -ms-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out; work in IE 10 alone?

Tags: javascript, css, transition

I have been playing around with some CSS3 + JavaScript today.

Below you have my code, (was trying to make the world's smallest image fading gallery, don't know if I succeeded).

I am not quite sure how to set the CSS though. See comment questions below:

```
-ms-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out; // Will this allone work in IE 10?       
transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out; // Why do we set this?
```

**Maybe the world's smallest JS-Gallery:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>HB - CSS3 + JS Gallery</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
body{margin:0;text-align:center;font:200px/500px georgia}
#g{background:#000;margin:0 auto;width:960px;height:500px;overflow:hidden}
#g div{
-webkit-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;      
transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
opacity:0;position:absolute;height:500px;width:960px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="g">
<div style="background:#090">1</div>
<div style="background:#096">2</div>
<div style="background:#963">3</div>
<div style="background:#CC0">4</div>
</div>
<script>
function i(){c[a].style.opacity='1'}function o(){c[a].style.opacity='0'}var g=document.getElementById('g'),c=g.children,l=c.length-1,f=function(){if(a==l){o();a=0;i()}else{o();a++;i()}};a=0;i();setInterval(f,4000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would think/hope you'd be setting the vendor specific transition properties (moz/o/webkit) too since all the modern browsers have been able to do transitions for years.

Comment: Rob, Thanks for your comment. I'm not shore I understands what you mean. Can you show me by adding it to the code?

Comment: I guess I missed that you already had the other vendors in your full markup example. I only looked at the two lines at the top.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
-ms-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out; // Will this allone work in IE 10?
```

If Microsoft have implemented a vendor-specific implementation of `transition` in Internet Explorer then this will be triggered by the `-ms-transition` property declaration, assuming that the arguments meet the specification they've implemented.

[Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition) suggests that IE 10 has, indeed, implemented the `-ms-transition` property, as does the [MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh466382.aspx), though it's non-specific as to which version of IE this is implemented in...

```
transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out; // Why do we set this?
```

We set this in order that once the standard implementation of `transition` is finalised and implemented this will override any interim vendor-specific implementations

Comment: Thanks for the info David! BoltClock, have yoiu tried? (I only have IE9 opn my computer...)

Comment: @user1087110: The [IE10 Test Drive](https://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive) contains demos of CSS3 transitions which can be viewed in the IE10 platform preview. The first two IE10 PPs will run on Windows 7, but I'm not sure if they're still available for download...

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft implemented the prefix and prefix-free versions at the same time.

So for your example

```
-ms-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out; // This will never be used because,
transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;     // This line will always overwrite it
```

View [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luckyllama/yER6B/) in IE10 and you'll see that both work just fine. If you declare both the prefix and the prefix-free version, the second declaration will take precedence.