# CSS Transition is not working for IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make the sticky footer to fade in from top and fade out to bottom. My code seems to work perfectly fine for Google Chrome, Firefox, etc. But it is not working at all for IE11.
Below is my code for CSS.
Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

```css
.sticky-footer-show {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
       -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
          transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
  
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
} //.sticky-footer-show

.sticky-footer-remove {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
       -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
          transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
          
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  height: 0;
} //.sticky-footer-remove
```

Comment: go have a look at : https://caniuse.com/#search=cubic-bezier And look if some of the 'known_issues' are concerning you

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the `-ms-` prefix

But it should also work with just transition according this answer [CSS3 + Javascript - Will -ms-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out; work in IE 10 alone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689071/css3-javascript-will-ms-transitionopacity-1s-ease-in-out-work-in-ie-10-al)

But internet explorer being internet explorer there might be something hindering it.

```css
.sticky-footer-show {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
       -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
      -ms-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
          transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
  
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -ms-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
} //.sticky-footer-show

.sticky-footer-remove {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
       -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
      -ms-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
          transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
          
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  -ms-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  height: 0;
} //.sticky-footer-remove
```

Have you tried using it all in the transition command?

```
 .sticky-footer-show, .sticky-footer-remove {
    -webkit-transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
         -o-transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
        -ms-transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
            transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
 }
 .sticky-footer-remove {
       height: 0;
 }
```

Advice: Don't try to support IE11 with fancy graphic dodas. Let them have the quick move to other state but have your webpage functional. IE11 will be used by now that half the internet is broken and move on to chrome/firefox/edge at some point.

Comment: I did trying putting  -ms-transition: all 1s; but it still does not work in IE11. Do you have any other solutions that I can try?

Comment: Thank you for your reply and updated answer. I tried your solution but that still doesn't fix the problem in IE11...

Comment: Can you edit in a working snippet, so theres something to play with?